Multithreaded Rendezvous Error During Milvus Data Insertion - How to Fix?
I'm currently running a Python script to insert a dataset of approximately 10 million vectors into a Milvus collection. While the insertion process works well for the first 40 batches of 10,000 records, I consistently encounter the following error after that point:
[describe_collection] retry: X, cost: Y, reason: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:127.0.0.1:19530: connection attempt timed out before receiving SETTINGS frame>

Here is the script I am using for insertion:
import numpy as np
from dtx_data_tools.iterate import batched, map_threaded

times = []
files = [f'agg_dataset/{fp}' for fp in os.listdir('agg_dataset') if 'parquet' in fp]

db_ids_set = set()
counter = 0

for batch_file in files:
    prep_start = time.time()
    df = pd.read_parquet(batch_file).drop_duplicates(subset='scrape_uuid', keep="last")
    
    insert_ids = set(df['scrape_uuid'].tolist())

    new_uuids = insert_ids - db_ids_set
    df = df[df['scrape_uuid'].isin(new_uuids)]
    
    db_ids_set.update(new_uuids)
    
    prep_end  = time.time() - prep_start
    print(f"prep time took {prep_end} seconds")
    
    start = time.time()
    transform_time = time.time()
    df['content_vector'] = df['encoding'].apply(lambda x: np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.float32))
    df = df[['scrape_uuid', 'content_vector']]
    print(f"Transform time: {time.time() - transform_time} seconds")
    
    try:
        client.insert(
            collection_name="milvus_orb_benchmark",
            data=df.to_dict('records')
        )
    
    counter += 10000
    print(f"Imported {counter} articles..., batch {batch_file} uploaded")
    end = time.time() - start
    print(f"batch insert_time took {end} seconds")
    times.append(end)

I suspect this issue is related to the gRPC server connection timing out. I've also attached my Milvus Operator configuration for reference:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: milvus
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: xxxxxx
apiVersion: milvus.io/v1beta1
kind: Milvus
metadata:
  name: milvus
  labels:
    app: milvus
spec:
  components:
    serviceAccountName: milvus
  config:
    minio:
      bucketName: xxxxxx
      # enable AssumeRole
      useIAM: true
      useSSL: true
  dependencies:
    storage:
      external: true
      type: S3
      endpoint:xxxxxxxx
      secretRef: ""

My Questions are:

How can I resolve the MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE error?
Are there specific settings I should modify in the Milvus configuration or gRPC server to prevent connection timeouts during large data insertion processes?
Is there a better way to handle the insertion of such a large dataset into Milvus without encountering this issue?

